# How do you keep simulator open after integration tests in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm doing integration testing with xcode and sometimes I want to test something out manually after the integration test finished running, but the simulator always closes after the tests are done. Is there any way to keep the simulator open and running after the test finished?

Something slightly better than `for (;;);` would be nice

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is uncheck "Stop when Run Completes" in Instruments.

[image: Instruments Script Options screenshot]